# Pass a Struct array ByRef from C# to C++ and get it back

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, dllimport

I've a very weird issue when calling a CPP dll.

I can call the method passing an struct array (with several positions) marshalled and loop it and set data to it as well. But when the code comes back to C#, the array has only one position.

For example, I create an array of my struct with 3 position (0, 1, 2), in the C++ Dll I receive the entire array and do nothing with it and when the execution returns to the C# Caller, the array has only one position on the array, with the first item.

The code:

C++ side:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int ViewItems(int * nTotalItems, void ** paramStruct) 
{
    // TODO nothing here.
    return 1;
}
```

C# side:

```
[DllImport(@"MyCustomLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ViewItems(ref int resultItemsCount, ref MyStruct[] MyStruct);
```

Invoke:

```
var resultSize = 3;
var resultStruct = new MyStruct[3];

for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++)
{
    resultStruct[i].SomePropValue = i+2;
}

// Before this, the resultStruct.Lenght is 3    
var resultCall = ViewItems(ref resultSize, ref resultStruct);
// After this, the resultStruct.Lenght is
```

Struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int SomePropValue;
}
```

I tried the following with no success:

- [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
- [In, Out]
- read other questions, but none of those had this issue.

Anyone have any idea of what I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

I removed the `ref` from the `DllImport` and put the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]` and `[In, Out]` decorator in `MyStruct` param.

Finally, I changed to `void * paramStruct` in C++ and finally all worked!